# Unable to create SOAP API call from API sample (Add data to DataExtension)

Tags: soap-api

Customer is going to create SOAP WebService call to add data to a DE.
However when they generated source files from WSDL (S7), they found at least 4 class/methods of sample source are not defined in these source files.

・Soap stub = init();　<- No Soap class

・CreateResponse createResponse = stub.create(createRequest); <- No Soap class

・dataExtensionObject.setClient(clientID); <-No setClient  (I guess it's 
extended..)

・createRequest.setObjects(apiObjects); <- No setObjects, setObjectsArray instead..

They referred following sample.

Adding Data to Data Extension Object -> Sample Java Code (Axis 1.4) - Adding Information to a Data Extension Object
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_data_to_data_extension_object/

Their platform is Axis, JDK1.6, and going to use Java.
They doubt the sample source is not compatible with Axis1.6

Q1) Is there a sample source compatible with Axis1.6 version?

Q2) Or can they compile the sample without 4 sentences above?

Q3) When they generate source using batch command, do they need to consider any option argument? or a set of source generated is everytime same?

Answer (score 0):

for the errors listed in this part:

```
Soap stub = init();　<- No Soap class
CreateResponse createResponse = stub.create(createRequest); <- No Soap class
dataExtensionObject.setClient(clientID); <-No setClient (I guess it's extended..)
createRequest.setObjects(apiObjects); <- No setObjects, setObjectsArray instead..
```

You have not included in your project all the classes related to the package "com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal": Soap.class, DataExtensionObject.class, ext...

You need to run mvn generate-sources